# Are escape sequences and escape characters the same thing in PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering if escape sequences and escape characters the same thing in PHP?

Comment: Do you mean `\‍‍‍` as the escape character in PHP strings and `\'` as an escape sequence?

Comment: yes I was talking about strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The "escape character" is the backslash (`\`). An "escape sequence" is the escape character followed by another character which is to be interpreted specially(`\"`, `\n`, etc.).